# Movement and Spell-Out of Heads

Tags: copula, movement, malay

Generally, DPs need to move to certain positions or configurations in order to check for case features (among other things) and allow spell-out. For example, raising predicates raise the subject of an embedded non-finite clause to [Spec, IP] of the matrix clause to check for NOM case, which the embedded clause is unable to assign.

Mary seems to be sick
*It seems Mary to be sick

so far, this is true of phrases.

> Are there any cases of heads (e.g. verbs, auxiliaries, modals, etc.)
>   in any languages that require movement to a certain position or
>   configuration (e.g. [Head, IP]) in order to be spelt-out?

I'm coming up with an analysis of Malay copulas that goes along the lines of the question above based on the observation that they are nonverbal, cannot occur in non-finite clauses, are non-overt when there are aspectual markers, negators and/or modal verbs in the same clause, etc.

If there is any literature on the topic, please send me the link.

Comment: I want to mention that I does not check NOM case marker. v and V head does that. The reason of movement from v-spec to I-spec is not motivated for checking NOM, but EPP feature.

Comment: @ErayErdin Thanks. Could you give me a reference to this?

Comment: This might give you an idea on how cases are inserted: http://www2.hawaii.edu/~yotsuka/pubs/Ch4.pdf | For further details, you might take Andrew Radford's books on Minimalist Program as a reference.